# What kind of significant magical item that is not overpowered could fit?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items

I plan to set a side quest into the adventure of the starter set. It is started by a riddle the party has to solve in the beginning of the campaign. The quest reward should be a magical item that feels really awesome, while not decreasing the difficulty of the adventure too much. So drastically increasing stats or granting additional strong powers is not what I'm looking for.

So:
Are there any items that feel notably powerful while not contradicting the restrictions mentioned before?
If so, are any of them useful for all characters, regardless of race/class?

I'm not expecting you to make a list, but rather a reference to such items in official material, so that I can look up the best fit for my self.

Comment: This is too broad and unclear both.  There are many magical items that are "awesome" (pure opinion)  and "for any class" but not "granting strong powers" (unclear how this interacts with awesome).

Comment: @mxyzplk: the awesome part wasn't even really considered of me as objective, but just more describtive. Either way, actually I'm just asking for a refference where to find strong items (where strong is an scaleable value of the official material, therefor nto opinion based). Admited, in a breakdown this would have been a not so much high quality post, as I expected it to be when I was writing it. but still ontopic.

Comment: @MarshallTigerus Please don't answer questions using comments.

Answer (score 3):

We can't really tell you what will be 'significant but not overpowered' for your group's power level, expectations of difficulty, etc. (and if we could, it would probably be a uselessly long list). Your best bet is probably to pick up a copy of the DMG and search the list of magic items (starting on p. 137) for an item that's interesting but has no numerical effect, nor powers that make upcoming challenges trivial. A bag of holding is a classic item not useful for combat per se, but be warned that creative adventurers have been known to really test the limits of the game and the DM's patience with them.

Comment: Thats why I mentioned which offical adventure we are actually in. A bag of holding sounds allready suitable sweet for my purposes. But where to find such lists in the dmg. Im actually reading the dmg first page to last and want to avoid crossreading. But in the index i didnt even noticed where such a list could be. Maybe you mean the phb? I own that one too but there I didnt even look onto the index yet.

Comment: Magic items are in the DMG. Looking at the [table of contents](http://www.enworld.org/forum/content.php?2006-It-s-the-DMG-TABLE-OF-CONTENTS!-Plus-FIREARMS!), it's in chapter 7, at page 137. (If you don't have the DMG, a fair few items are also in the [SRD](http://www.5esrd.com/gamemastering/magic-items)).

Comment: @Adeptus: If this should be reopened again, I would welcome it if you put that in as answer.